# Angularjs Factory not loading when added as dependency in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am very new to Angularjs and this is my first try to build an app with it. I've following file loaded in my `index.html` file.

```
<!--Angularjs-->
<script src="assets/js/vendor/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/vendor/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--SleekDocketAppJS-->
<script src="app/app.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app/app.route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--Controllers-->
<script src="app/components/dashboard/controller/dashboardController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app/components/product/controller/productController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

His is my `app.module.js` file and I am trying to add a factory here name **AuthFactory**

```
'use strick';

var docket = angular.module("docket",['ngRoute']);

//Factory
docket.factory('AuthFactory',function(){

    console.log('auth factory');
    var authdata = {};
    authdata.name = "user 1";
    return (authdata);
});

//Running
docket.run(function(){
    console.log("runing...");
});
```

This is my `app.route.js` file where I am calling my controllers based on route.

```
'use strict';

var docket = angular.module('docket');

docket.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/",
    {
            controller:"DashboardController",
            templateUrl: "app/components/dashboard/view/dashboard.html"
        })
        .when("/product",{
            controller:"productController",
            templateUrl: "app/components/product/view/product.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/'
        });
}]);
```

My simple `dashboardController.js` looks like this

```
var app = angular.module('docket');

    app.controller('DashboardController',['$scope, AuthFactory', function($scope, AuthFactory){

        console.log('dash controller');
        //console.log(AuthFactory);
    }]);
```

But when I am trying to run the app using loading the service `DashboardController`, I get his error. But if I remove the service from the controller dependency, there is no error.
[image: AuthFactory Error]

Comment: `use strick` in `app.module.js` should be corrected to `use strict`.

Comment: @jason328 thanks for pointing out.. but unfortunately this doesn't solved the issue :(

Comment: DI argument list should not just be all one string, they should be separated by commas. Look at the error message clearly, It is looking for `"$scope, AuthFactoryProvider"`. When you see any error switch to angular.js instead of angular.min.js so that you see more verbose error in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is typo mistake " ' " after $scope

```
app.controller('DashboardController',['$scope, AuthFactory', function($scope, AuthFactory)
```

Change to

```
app.controller('DashboardController',['$scope', 'AuthFactory', function($scope, AuthFactory)
```

Comment: Gahhh. You beat me by 1 minute.

Comment: Wonderful! It worked.  I wasn't attentive enough to learn how to quote "'". Thanks.

Comment: WOW - I am not a novice Angular developer; and had spent 30 minutes trying to figure this out. In a last-minute-before-going-mad-moment, I decided to google... Your "fix" came up.

I had ALSO missed out a single quote. Angular was failing silently (any good reason for it to be on mute? Surely it would have helped to cry a little!?!?!?!) 

Thank you!!!